Problem with copying font properties from a list box to a label
I am using Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications and have a standard form containing a list box (”ListBox1”) and a label (”Label1”). I am trying to copy bold and italic properties from the list box to the label, as shown in the code below:
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim FontHeight As Double
    
    With Label1
        Debug.Print "Label1   :", .Font.Name, Font.Size, .Font.Bold, .Font.Italic, Font.Weight
    End With
    With ListBox1
        Debug.Print "ListBox1 :", .Font.Name, Font.Size, .Font.Bold, .Font.Italic, Font.Weight
    End With
    With Label1
        .AutoSize = False
        .Height = 100
        .Font.Name = ListBox1.Font.Name
        .Font.Size = ListBox1.Font.Size
'        If ListBox1.Font.Bold Then
'            .Font.Bold = True
'        Else
'            .Font.Bold = False
'        End If
        .Font.Bold = ListBox1.Font.Bold
        .Font.Italic = ListBox1.Font.Italic
        .AutoSize = True
        FontHeight = .Height
        Debug.Print "Label1   :", .Font.Name, Font.Size, .Font.Bold, .Font.Italic, Font.Weight
    End With
End Sub

The output from the three Debug-calls are as follows:
Label1   :    Tahoma         8.25         False         False          400 
ListBox1 :    Tahoma         8.25         False         False          400 
Label1   :    Tahoma         8.25         True          True           400 

As shown both by the output and by visual inspection, the label text is now both bold and italic!
I set a breakpoint at the line
.Font.Bold = ListBox1.Font.Bold
Before executing the line both .Bold values were False, but after execution .Fold.Bold becomes True.
I tried instead to use the lines commented out with the same result: The line
.Fold. Bold = False
results in .Fold.Bold becoming True!?!
The Visual Basic Reference states that Bold and Italic (as well as Underline and StrikeThrough) as Boolean variables and informs that ”Conversely, setting Weight to anything over 550 sets Bold to True; setting Weight to 550 or less sets Bold to False.”. In my case Weight = 400, so this is not the explanation.
What is the reason for this strange behavior and how can it be avoided?

In Excel  I could not reproduce this error.
Which application you are working in?
Which version
Can you reproduce this on a other machine?

Same as in the previous comment. I am not able to reproduce the error.

I can confirm this behavior. I cannot explain it. I would consider it a bug in the VBA runtime, and I am usually very skeptical if someones talks about bugs in VBA.
A wild guess is that it has to do with how Font objects are created and cached - as far as I remember there are some optimization routines that try to avoid that too many Font objects exists.
I did some experiments. I thought I found it: When not copying the font.name or when copying font.name after copying the Bold and Italic property, it worked correctly. Wanted to share this in this answer, first copied your code again to confirm, commented out the one line that copies the font name - and the font of the label went Bold.
I found another workaround, and so far I never had an issue with that: When assigning the label and listbox to two control variables and copy the font properties using those variables, it seems to work all the time
Dim ctrlFrom As Control, ctrlTo As Control

Set ctrlFrom = Me.ListBox1
Set ctrlTo = Me.Label1
ctrlTo.Font.Name = ctrlFrom.Font.Name
ctrlTo.Font.Bold = ctrlFrom.Font.Bold
ctrlTo.Font.Italic = ctrlFrom.Font.Italic
ctrlTo.Font.Size = ctrlFrom.Font.Size

You could make a Subroutine from that:
Sub copyFont(fromCtrl As Control, toCtrl As Control)
    toCtrl.Font.Name = fromCtrl.Font.Name
    toCtrl.Font.Size = fromCtrl.Font.Size
    toCtrl.Font.Bold = fromCtrl.Font.Bold
    toCtrl.Font.Italic = fromCtrl.Font.Italic
End Sub

I would suggest that you call this routine from the Activate-trigger, not from the Initialize as at that moment, the controls may not really be ready to be modified.
Would be nice if you (or anyone else) could give some Feedback if this solved the issue.

Before I tested it with the Initialize I tested it with a command button to make sure it is not a initialize problem (I agree - that using the initialize of a userform should be used very carefully)

@FunThomas
I am glad that you could reproduce the error. I am gladder that you also found a solution: Updating Bold and Italic before updating Font.Name indeed avoids the problem.
Thank you very much for your solution!
